# DocumentCollection count is 5 but only get 1 document

Tags: java, lotus-notes

In IBM Lotus Domino I have built a Java Agent. In this agent I am getting a View which has orderlines:

```
View orderLinesView = CurrentDatabase.getView("OrderLinesOnId");
```

The view has a sorted column: **ID_Order** which is also categorized.

I did the following to get all documents in the view with the same ID_Order:

```
 Vector keyRegel = null;
 keyRegel = new Vector(); 
 keyRegel.add(orderDocument.getItemValueString("ID_Order"));
 DocumentCollection orderLineCollection =  orderLinesView.getAllDocumentsByKey(keyRegel, true);
```

Now I want to loop through all the documents and print the description:

```
System.out.println("Count orderRegelcollection:" + 
Document orderLineDocument = orderLineCollection.getFirstDocument();

while (orderLineDocument != null) {
  System.out.println("description " + orderLineDocument.getItemValueString("description"));
   orderLineDocument = orderLineCollection.getNextDocument();
}
```

On running, it does print 1 document and after the first loop it finishes. However, in my view I clearly see 5 documents with the same ID_Order.
The strange thing is that it takes only the last document in the view (when I searched on ID_Order)

[image]

The complete code is like this:

```
   View relationsView = dbRelatie.getView("Relations");;
          Document relationDocument = relationsView.getFirstDocument();
 while (relationDocument != null) {

      Vector key = null;
      key = new Vector(); 
      key.add("");
      key.add(relationDocument.getItemValueString("getDebtor"));
      DocumentCollection orderDocumentCollection =  TotalOrdersView.getAllDocumentsByKey(key, true);
      Document orderDocument = orderDocumentCollection.getFirstDocument();

      while (orderDocument != null) {
```

And then i get the orderlines..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is never getting the next document.

In you while loop change the last line to

```
orderLineDocument = orderLinesView.getNextDocument();
```

Also, alternatively since you have already built a collection. You can use that to get next document as

```
orderLineDocument = orderLineCollection.getNextDocument();
```

From the documentation an example class looks like this. This example although is getting all documents in database and creates DocumentCollection. The difference between your code and below example is that you are creating the collection from the view. Nonetheless this method should work for you too.

> This agent gets all the documents in a database.
>
> ```
> import lotus.domino.*;
> public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
>   public void NotesMain() {
>     try {
>       Session session = getSession();
>       AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
>       // (Your code goes here)
>       Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
>       DocumentCollection dc = db.getAllDocuments();
>       Document tmpdoc;
>       Document doc = dc.getFirstDocument();
>       while (doc != null) {
>         System.out.println(doc.getItemValueString("Subject"));
>         tmpdoc = dc.getNextDocument();
>         doc.recycle();
>         doc = tmpdoc;
>       }
>     } catch(Exception e) {
>       e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

[Documentation for DocumentCollection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDOCUMENTCOLLECTION_CLASS_JAVA.html)

Comment: He yea sorry I had orderLineCollection.getNextdocument(); i wrongly typed it in to the question.. And the reason why I use getAllDocumentsByKey is because I dont want a loop through 100.000+ documents

Comment: No problem. :) Which is why I said you can make the document Collection in any way , either by doing `getAllDocuments()` or `getDocumentByKeys()` the collection object will be same you just need to get the next document out of it in the loop, in the way I have mentioned above.

Comment: :) Thanks for replying, I have orderLineCollection.getNextDocument();  But I only get the last document. so I see 5 if I look it up in the view But I only get the last

Comment: Oh you are still missing the crucial step of assigning the value. Look at my answer again. In the while loop do the assignment along with calling the method on the collection so  you need `orderLineDocument = orderLineCollection.getNextDocument();` not just `orderLineCollection.getNextDocument();`

Comment: Ok. It would have been just easier if you rewrite your question with all code in one go. :) How about trying and printing the count. See if the collection really has 5 documents. If not, the problem may be in the key. Also you can run debugger to step through and see.

Comment: Further I see your while loop is checking for orderDocument!=null but you are assigning orderLineDocument ... If this is also not the problem and you have it correct in your code,  I suggest you share the entire code so I can see what's going on.

Comment: I already fixed it, I had used getNextDocument on orderDocument collection and not on orderLineCollection .. :( thanks for help!